# LINQ concept in C#

Tags: c#, linq

## Write a program to find the vehicles released between certain year.

1. class Vehicle is already given for your reference.
2. class Program contains a hard-coded list with vehicle information in the 'vehicleList' attribute.

a) Implement method 'getVehicleName'.

public static void getVehicleName(int fromYear, int toYear)          //method signature

This method must must display the vehicle names (from the given list) released between the fromYear and toYear (including these years).  USING LINQ CONCEPT

b) Implement method 'Main'.

Get the from year and to year from the user. Pass it to 'getVehicleName' method.

NOTE : NEED NOT call 'getMyExpression' method in Main.

c) Implement method 'getMyExpression'

public static Expression getMyExpression(int fromYear, int toYear)

This method snippet is already given for you. THIS METHOD IS FOR TESTING YOUR LINQ QUERY EXPRESSION OR LINQ METHOD EXTENSION.  So fill your query expression or method extension in the space holder provided. ONLY THE QUERY EXPRESSION OR METHOD EXTENSION.  Nothing more need to be implemented in this class.

## I am getting an error - `LinqApp1.Vehicle' does not contain a definition for` Where'.

## Vehicle.cs

```
namespace LinqApp1                
{
public class Vehicle          
{
    public String VehicleId{get; set; }
    public String VehicleName{ get; set; }
    public String Brand { get; set; }
    public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }

    public Vehicle(String vehicleId, String vehicleName, String brand,int releaseYear)
    {
        this.VehicleId = vehicleId;
        this.VehicleName = vehicleName;
        this.Brand = brand;
        this.ReleaseYear = releaseYear;
    }
    
}
```

}

## Program.cs

```
 namespace LinqApp1                //DO NOT CHANGE the namespace name
 {

  public class Program         //DO NOT CHANGE the class name
  {
    /** DO NOT CHANGE this 'List' declaration with initialized values  **/
    public static List<Vehicle> vehicleList = new List<Vehicle>()
                            {
                                new Vehicle("HO345","CRV","Honda",2015),
                                new Vehicle("HY562","Creta","Hyundai",2017),
                                new Vehicle("RE198","Duster","Reanult",2014),
                                new Vehicle("MA623","Spacio","Suzuki",2014),
                                new Vehicle("TR498","Nexon","Tata",2015),
                                new Vehicle("TR981","Zest","Tata",2016),
                                new Vehicle("HO245","WRV","Honda",2018)

                            };

    static void Main(string[] args)   //DO NOT Change this 'Main' signature
    {
        int fromy,toy;
        Console.Write("Enter From Year : ");
        fromy = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter To Year : ");
        toy = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        getVehicleName(fromy,toy);
    }

    public static void getVehicleName(int fromYear, int toYear)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> L = from v in Vehicle 
        where(v.releaseYear >= fromYear && v.releaseYear <= toYear)
        select v.VehicleName; 
        
    }
    

     /** DO NOT CHANGE this ParameterExpression **/  
    public static ParameterExpression variableExpr = Expression.Variable(typeof(IEnumerable<Vehicle>), "sampleVar");
    
    public static Expression getMyExpression(int fromYear, int toYear)
    {  
        Expression assignExpr = Expression.Assign(variableExpr, Expression.Constant(vehicle.Where(v => v.releaseYear >= fromYear && v.releaseYear <= toYear.select(n => n.VehicleName))));
        return assignExpr;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Please read the FAQ [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822). Copying and pasting the homework into the question is not considered a good technique.

Comment: Try `from v in vehicleList` instead; it needs to be a collection and you're currently referring to a class type instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query against your `vehicleList` instead:

```
public static void getVehicleName(int fromYear, int toYear)
{
    IEnumerable<string> L = from v in vehicleList 
    where(v.ReleaseYear >= fromYear && v.ReleaseYear <= toYear)
    select v.VehicleName; 

}
```

In your `getMyExpression` method:

```
vehicle.Where(v => v.releaseYear >= fromYear && v.releaseYear <= toYear.select(n => n.VehicleName)))
```

should be:

```
vehicleList.Where(v => v.ReleaseYear >= fromYear && v.ReleaseYear <= toYear).Select(n => n))
```

Comment: I am getting a type conversion error for v.VehicleName : Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>'.

Comment: @AadityaAgrawal There you go.

Comment: Can you please verify the method chain. I am getting an error : Type `int' does not contain a definition for `select' and no extension method `select' of type `int' could be found.

Comment: @AadityaAgrawal The only other problem is that `ReleaseYear` needs the capital "R" …I verified that this works.

Comment: I have changed all r to capital in ReleaseYear. 'select(n => n.VehicleName)' This is the part where I am getting the error. Is the format correct?

Comment: Okay, the error is gone but the method isn't returning anything.

Comment: @AadityaAgrawal No error? Hmm... replace `.Select(n => n.VehicleName)` with `.Select(n => n)` at the end, because `variableExpr` is expecting `typeof(IEnumerable<Vehicle>)`.